# Why can't I get a span to line up right next to a set of images?

Tags: css, margin, html

I am lining up a span with an image background next to a list of images and the span shows up about 40px below the images (I want them to be lined up right next to them)

Here is my html

```
  <div id="people">
    <img width="44" height="44" src="http://www.mysite.com/image.png" class="personImage" rel="/Person/CorpInfo/74" title="Name"> 

    <img width="44" height="44" src="http://www.mysite.com/image2.png" class="personImage" rel="/Person/CorpInfo/79" title="Name"> 

    <span class="initials" rel="/Person/CorpInfo/839" title="Name">YA</span>

    <img width="44" height="44" src="http://www.mysite.com/image3.png" class="personImage" rel="/Person/CorpInfo/49" title="Name"> 
 </div>
```

As you can see, I am showing a list of images but in certain cases, I show a span with their initials and a background "generic" picture. As mentioned, for some reason, the span is showing up lower than the images.

Here is the css for this "initials" span (if that helps)

```
.initials 
{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 24px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 44px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 line-height: 44px;
 font-weight: 500;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url('/content/Images/generic1small.png') no-repeat 0 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 44px;
}
```

and here is the css for the "personImage class

```
.personImage
{
   display:inline;
}
```

If I apply this hack, it seems to line up:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .initials {    margin: -40px 5px 0px 0px;}
</style>
```

but I really want to avoid this as its causing some other issues on my page (not relevant for this question).

Any idea why I can't get this span to line up against these images?

Comment: an example on something like jsbin.com would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing

```
.initials {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

to

```
.initials {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```